# Bootstrap3 3-column layout to 2-column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I,m trying to make a responsive website using bootstrap3 that is 3-column in large screens and 2-column in medium:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4" id="sidebar1"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8" id="main"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4" id="sidebar2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/yfJF1flD0V
but this code not working properly and on medium size, sidebar2 goes in a new row and i want sidebar2 goes below sidebar1 directly. how can i do that?

Comment: You've got too many columns in md layout 8+4+4 = 16 - column is 12 max. Although that won't solve your problem, it will make it easier to see... I'll post a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it with jQuery.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4" id="sidebar1"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8" id="main"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4" id="sidebar2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and jQuery:

```
function mediumResponsive() {
// Reset everything
  $( '#main>div' ).removeClass('col-md-8');
  $("#sidebar1").next().andSelf().unwrap();
  $( "#sidebar2" ).insertAfter( $( "#main" ) );
  if ($('#is-md').is(":visible")) {
// Do medium responsive
  $( "#sidebar2" ).insertAfter( $( "#sidbar1" ) );
  $("#sidebar1").next().andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="container-fluid"');
  $( '#main>div' ).addClass('col-md-8');
  };
};
$(document).ready(mediumResponsive);
$(window).bind( "resize", mediumResponsive );
```

and it works.
Please tell me your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to duplicate some of your content and use `hidden-lg` and `visible-lg`.

[**DEMO ON BOOTPLY**](http://www.bootply.com/S8BGx575Cz)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <!-- on md only -->
      <div class="col-md-4 hidden-lg">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 grey1">
            Sidebar 1 md - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 grey2">
            Sidebar 2 md - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- on lg only -->
      <div class="col-lg-2 visible-lg">
        Sidebar 1 lg - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-push-8 visible-lg">
        Sidebar 2 lg - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
      </div>

      <!-- on all -->
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-pull-2">
          Main all - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Because of the requirement to stack your sidebars on `md` screens with main content to their right, you've got to put the sidebars in a containing column. But that containing column then makes it so you can't bookend your sidebars around that same main content in `lg` screens. Hence the need to use visible and hidden. I always feel like they're a bit clunky, but otherwise I think you won't get exactly what you want...

Comment: thnks for your answer. but I don't like visible-* , hidden-*. isn't there another way?