# Bootstrap 3 - 3 Column layout into 2 column layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've seen various "solutions" for BS2, however I'm looking for the best way to achieve the following with BS3, without duplicating content.

Similar to how Twitter works; 3 column layout for desktops, but when hitting a tablet/'md' view, the right column stacks content below the left content, and the main content spans the full width:

Desktop:

```
----------------------------------
   (A) 3  |    (B) 6     | (C) 3
----------------------------------
```

Tablet & Below

```
--------------------------
  (A) 3  |   (B) 9
  (C) 3  |    
--------------------------
```

Similar:
- [Bootstrap3 3-column layout to 2-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851932/bootstrap3-3-column-layout-to-2-column)

I've been trying to use pull/push but with no luck.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3" ui-view="left-sidebar"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-push-6" ui-view="right-sidebar"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-col-lg-pull-3 col-xs-push-3" ui-view="container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any simpler solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you need. The lenght of the paragraphs is not confortable to show on different screen widths the usability of the code below.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-push-3 col-xs-9 col-md-6">B Pellentesque placerat metus et turpis ornare, eu porta leo tempus. Vestibulum imperdiet aliquam purus, ac blandit lacus consectetur et. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vivamus sed nisi pharetra ex sagittis laoreet. </div>
        <div class="col-xs-pull-9 col-xs-3 col-md-pull-6">A Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc nec rutrum metus. Integer ut nibh ut lectus euismod congue. Aenean feugiat lobortis ipsum, a dignissim nisl imperdiet in. Etiam at erat sagittis, consequat lacus vitae, interdum lectus. Maecenas rhoncus ligula nulla, sed vestibulum leo porta ac. Vestibulum tincidunt efficitur eros eget molestie. Duis luctus ultricies eros vitae ultrices.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">C Fusce ultricies sit amet ipsum id ullamcorper. Suspendisse potenti. Nam quis convallis lorem. Vestibulum venenatis faucibus urna, a laoreet felis imperdiet et. </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If it helps, +1.